# C# password protect an embedded db4o database

Tags: c#, database, passwords, db4o

I am creating an application which will run on a users machine to store records in a db4o database. As part of the application, there will be a login form displayed when it starts up. How would I go about creating a password for the database and then check it? Is this possible or will I need to create a separate file that is read for a username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret that as the database being stored locally - if so I would recommend encryption, as it is running locally the user could bypass your application and read the database directly from the file system.
DB40 supports encryption out of the box according to their website, but only protects from "unauthenticated" users, as the encryption key will be shared - not per user.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I shall look at now and try get it implemented